# EMS Advanced Data Export VCL - export to Excel with custom field names

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

I cant seem to figure this one out.

Exporting data to Excel works OK but I do not want to use the original table field names but ones of my choice.

Right now, the original field names get exported (with the data,of course). `QExport4XLS1` is linked to the data-set. I tried to use `qeCustomSource41` (custom source) and changing field names -  it worked OK but no data got exported. Only the field names.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this ? I never used these components before, so I am just trying them out. The documentation is horrible.

Comment: I don't know about EMS, but try setting your DataSet fields `DisplayLabel`.

Comment: documentation says you should provide column names as .Value[...] properties of the additionally created stringlist. http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/tools/advancedexport/faq#1569

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the only way to do this is through QExport4Dialog1 and not through QExport4XLS1.